# User Defined Exception class not handled by Spring MVC Exception Handlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I created my own exception and trying to handle it with spring MVC.

Spring Handling all exceptions as it should except my own exceptions(User Defined). **What is the problem, how to handle User Defined Exceptions in Spring MVC?**

I used `@ExceptionHandler` in my controller and in `@ControllerAdvice`, used `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` bean in Dispatcher servlet no help. In every stage all the System defined exceptions are handled as expected.

*User Defined Exception:*

```
public class GeneralUserException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String message;

    public GeneralUserException (String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

*Exception Handler in controller:*

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = GeneralUserException.class)
public String defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, GeneralUserException e)  {
    return "general_error";
}
```

*Exception Handler in @ControllerAdvice:*

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = GeneralUserException.class)
    public String defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, GeneralUserException e)  {
        return "general_error";
    }
}
```

*Bean in dispatcher Servlet Context (WebAppConfig):*

```
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.setProperty("GeneralUserException", "general_error");

        r.setExceptionMappings(mappings);  
        r.setDefaultErrorView("error");   

        return r;
    }

    ...
}
```

All these are not showing error page. But when I change `GeneralUserException` to `Exception`/`RuntimeException` it works. I tried to put full qualified name too.

I use spring, spring MVC, spring Security if it's helpful. And I don't use Spring Aspects.

**Note:** `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` is returning "error" page on error(so its working) for `DefaultErrorView`. When I use `RuntimeException` instead `GeneralUserException`  it returns "general_error" view so its working for `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Your `@ExceptionHandler` is rendered useless when you define a `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`. Use one or the other not both. (Unless you also add an `ExceptionHandlerExceptioNResolver` next to the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`. Also without a `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` it won't work either.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't use both. I tried each approach separately.  And I have `@EnableWebMvc`, just tried to shorten the code and cut off some parts in here.